# What is UDP Masquerading behavior when forwarding and listening on the same port to the same remote address?

Tags: iptables, nat, port-forwarding, nftables, dnat

Assuming the following:

```
||netns2|<-kernel routing-> netnsRoot| <-network routing-> |remote server|
```

#### netns2

- is a network namespace
- has a client that connects to the UDP server on UDP/5060

#### netnsRoot

- is the root network namespace (IE: typical linux routing)
- has a client that connects to the UDP server on UDP/5060
- Has ip_forward enabled and has a Masquerade rule for netns2

#### Server

- Only sees traffic from the netnsRoot external interface

How does Masquerade behave in the netnsRoot? I would expect that it would forward packets from `netns2` but the client in `netnsRoot` would receive all messages first. This is not what I think I am seeing, instead I am seeing `netns2` NAT punch and take over the port for a period of time.

Is this behavior documented anywhere?

Comment: You should check this: https://breakpointingbad.com/2021/09/08/Port-Shadows-via-Network-Alchemy.html and Netfilter mailing list: https://marc.info/?l=netfilter-devel&m=163240274903944&w=2 (this is a rfc, not sure anything can be done automatically about it yet)

Answer (score 0):

Ok decided to quantify this myself

```
||netna|<-kernel routing-> |netnsr|<-kernel routing->|netnb||
```

- netnsb has a route to netnsa
- netnsr has ip forward enabled

### Masquerade and netnsb client

enabling Masquerade in `netnsr`, and having a `netnsb` client connect to a `netnsa` server on 5060 from 5060 shows that 5060 is used exiting `netnsr`

### Masquerade and both client

enabling Masquerade in `netnsr`, having a `netnsb` client connect to a `netnsa` server on 5060 from 5060 and having the same client run in `netnsr` shows:

- netnsr client talking on 5060 externally
- netnsb client talking on 29683 externally

this is confirmed by the conntrack entries

```
udp      17 119 src=10.216.210.2 dst=10.216.100.2 sport=5060 dport=5060 src=10.216.100.2 dst=10.216.100.1 sport=5060 dport=29683 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=1
udp      17 119 src=10.216.100.1 dst=10.216.100.2 sport=5060 dport=5060 src=10.216.100.2 dst=10.216.100.1 sport=5060 dport=5060 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=1
```